# Expressing "Every student has passed at least one class" in FOL

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

My question:

> Express this phrase in first-order language: "Every student has passed at least one class".

This is my teacher's answer:

> We define $S(x)$ as "object $x$ is a student" , $C(x)$ as "object $x$ is
> a class" and $P(x,y)$ as a predicate logic - symbol which translates to
> "student $x$ has passed class $y$". So we have:
>
> $\forall x (S(x) \rightarrow \exists y [C(y) \land P(x,y)])$.

My question is what about : "$\forall x S(x) \exists y ( C(y) \land P(x,y))$". Why the second one is wrong?

Comment: You have no logical connective between $S(x)$ and $\exists\ldots$, so your proposal is not a well-formed formula.

Comment: Your edit hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: The correct formula should read $\forall x (S(x) \to \exists y (C(y) \land P(x,y)))$, not $\forall x S(x) \to \exists y (C(y) \land P(x,y))$: The $\forall x$ must have scope over the whole implication, not just $S(x)$.

Comment: It sounds like you are intending $\forall x S(x)$ to mean "for all $x$ such that $S(x)$..." but that is not strictly valid first-order logic syntax.

Comment: thank you , for your answer. I think my teacher mentioned that , when we use $\forall$ we  should normally expect in order our sentence to make sense , to use $\rightarrow$ afterwards

Comment: i also added the parenthesis , as you said . I should put this parenthesis , because otherway , what I wrote meant that x in $P(x,y)$ could be anyhting , not necessarily  the (same) x from the left, that satisfied S(x), right?

Comment: @brucebanner: Yes: the problem without parentheses is that then, as you say, the $x$ in $P(x)$ is free; but also that the statement then means "If everyone is a student, then there is some class..."  -- but you don't want everyone in the universe to be a student, but rather say that for everyone it holds that if they is a student, then ... , and if not then not. This is achieved by having the implication in parentheses.

Comment: yes , yes makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you've read somewhere something like

> $\forall x \in \mathbb{N} P(x)$

and try to apply the same pattern to the sentence in question with $x \in \mathbb{N}$ corresponding to $S(x)$ and $P(x)$ to $\exists y ...$.

But the above is not strictly speaking a first-order formula, but just an abbrevation for

> $\forall x (x \in \mathbb{N} \to P(x))$

and is normally only used with set membership statements $x \in Y$, not predicates like $S(x)$.

If you are asserting two formulas $S(x)$, $\exists y ...$ then by the syntax of predicate logic, you must have a connective in between them so the whole thing becomes another formula, and that's missing in your proposal.

---

Besides, as mentioned in the comments,

> $\forall x S(x) \to \exists y (C(y) \land P(x,y))$

is *not* the correct solution. Your teacher probably wrote

> $\forall x (S(x) \to \exists y (C(y) \land P(x,y)))$

-- the $\forall x$ must range over the implication, not just the $S(x)$.

Comment: thank you , for your answer. I think my teacher mentioned that , when we use ∀ we should normally expect in order our sentence to make sense , to use → afterwards – do you agree?

Comment: Yes. As a rule of thumb, with $\forall$ use $\to$, with $\exists$ use $\land$, unless you are sure you want something else.

Comment: great, thank you so much